# changing div background firefox vs chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a div on my page where I want to change its background by clicking on it. The background can either be "transparent" with no color, or a reddish/pinkish color.

I have a javascript function that checks the current background-color and changes it based on that:

```
if (buttonBackground == "transparent") {
                //"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
 $('#delete_button_container_' + buttonNumber).css('background-color', '#ff9494');

} else if (buttonBackground == "rgb(255, 148, 148)") {

 $('#delete_button_container_' + buttonNumber).css('background', 'none');

}
```

the problem is that for a transparent color, chrome reads the background-color property as `"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"` but firefox reads it as `"transparent"`. However, they BOTH read the background-color property with the color '#ff9494' as `"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"`

so this is obviously causing an issue, if I have the if (transparent) chrome doesn't work, and if I have if (reba(0000)) firefox doesn't work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: **Never** rely on browsers returning the correct color, use a variable as a flag instead

Comment: maybe an answer with an example will help ;)

Comment: There's not really enough code to do that properly! Where's `buttonNumber` coming from, is this in a loop, do you need a flag on each element being changed, if so `data` is useful, but how ?

Comment: Lets say you have **myDiv** jquery element, than when you set the color, also set element's data: `myDiv.data('myColor', 'transparent')` for example.

Comment: @skobaljic wait, but how do I set the data on first click when I set the color if I can't even get into the first If statement? the first if is also checking for color and that's where I'm having the issue

Comment: Use on div click event and there `var currentColor = $(this).data('myColor')`, than you can use `if ( currentColor=='transparent' )` or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve this with a class. You can have `delete_button_container`'s default state be transparent or the color, it doesn't matter, but add a class that overrides that default to set the color.

HTML:

`<div class="deleteButtonContainer transBackground"></div>`

JS:

```
if($('#delete_button_container_' + buttonNumber).hasClass('transBackground')){
 $(this).removeClass('transBackground');
} else {
 $(this).addClass('transBackground');
}
```

CSS:

```
.deleteButtonContainer{
    background-color: rgb(255, 148, 148);
}

.deleteButtonContainer.transBackground{
    background-color: none;
}
```

EDIT: Changed the selector to use the ID OP was using.

Comment: hmmm... true but I can't do that, I'm already using class/Id for other functionality reasons I believe... I'll have to see if I can change that and use this method

Comment: You can add as many classes as you want! And removeClass will ONLY remove that class, so you don't need to worry about whatever else you have set on it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the comments I did the following and it's working:

```
var transparent = false;
if (buttonBackground == "transparent" || buttonBackground == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
                transparent = true;
}

if (transparent) {
                //"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
 $('#delete_button_container_' + buttonNumber).css('background-color', '#ff9494');

} else if (buttonBackground == "rgb(255, 148, 148)") {

 $('#delete_button_container_' + buttonNumber).css('background', 'none');

}
```

Comment: You're still relying on what the browser returns. If a user has an older browser that for some reason returns hex, it all fails.

Comment: you're killing me :) I guess the below answer is better

Comment: In theory it is, but you don't need to add classes or change the DOM at all, you can use jQuery's `data` to store the state, all you need is a true-or-false value.

Comment: But of course, if you use classes to change the background as well,  the below answer is fine !